# Sitecore - get all indexed items

Tags: lucene, sitecore, sitecore7

I am using lucene search to get bucket items filtered by some string and this is my code:

```cs
var innerQuery = new FullTextQuery(myString);
                    var hits = searchContext.Search(innerQuery, searchIndex.GetDocumentCount());
```

Is there some query or something different that will let me get all indexed items? I tried with empty "myString" but there is an error that it cannot be empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Lucene.Net.Search.MatchAllDocsQuery`:

```cs
SearchHits hits = searchContext.Search(new MatchAllDocsQuery(), int.MaxValue);
```

Comment: Thanks for help :)